# Regular Expression to Split Text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to split text (chess notation) into separate lines for each move. A move is either move number (1.) and move (e4) if it is White to move or just the move (c5) if it is Black to move.
This is what I have as an example:

```
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 
Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. h3 e5 7. Nde2 h5 8.
g3 Be6
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
1. e4
c5
2. Nf3
d6
3. d4
cxd4
4. Nxd4
Nf6
5. Nc3
a6
6. h3
 e5
7. Nde2
h5 
8. g3
Be6
```

I have made some progress in finding a pattern that matches the first part but I am not sure how to do the actual split. Also there are rare cases where there is a part of my pattern in one line and the rest in the next line, e.g. *8.[new line here]g3* instead of *8. g3* which I would match.

```
[0-9]+\.\s?[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

This matches move numbers, the dot, the space and the actual move. But then I want to replace the next space and not the actual string. For the Black moves I was trying this

```
[^0-9][^.][A-Za-z0-9]+
```

but it keeps matching *. e4* (a White move) and not only the Black moves like *c5*.

Comment: I just thought that I actually want to replace a space if it is not between a move number and a move. I could use Replace: (?<!\.) with \r\n. But Wiktor was faster than I could edit my question and he has the better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like after the number with a dot, there are always two "words". Capture them and re-format the match as you need:

*Find What*: `(\d+\.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*`
*Replace With*: `$1 $2\n$3\n`

*Details*:

- `(\d+\.)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more digits and a `.`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more word chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 3 (`$3`): one or more word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do usually set it using this regex code.

Find: `.(\d+\.)(?=[\w]*) ?\n?`
Replace All: `\n$1`

See the result in attachment below

[image]